# Ninject issue in WebAPI2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to Ninject and currently trying to use it in a WebAPI2 project. It keeps telling me it can't find certain class files when I run the program (ResolutionExtensions.cs in particular seems to come up alot).

Here's the stack trace. It's complaining about no parameterless constructor but I attempted to look through other similar questions and none seemed apt.

```
<StackTrace>
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method) at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType) at Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create(ConstructorInfo constructor) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Injection\DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.cs:line 48 at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.ConstructorReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Strategies\ConstructorReflectionStrategy.cs:line 67 at Ninject.Planning.Planner.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateNewPlan>b__0(IPlanningStrategy s) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:line 109 at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:line 32 at Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan(Type type) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:line 109 at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:line 71 at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 77 at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157 at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 197 at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 165 at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 114 at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96 at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157 at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.TryGet[T](IEnumerable`1 iterator) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 270 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.TryGet(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 189 at WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject.NinjectDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
```

I'm not sure if it's trying to reference the dll or if there are actually class files it is supposed to be linked to but [here's an example of the file path it seems to be looking for (even though it does not exist on my local)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ8t2.jpg).

My controller looks like this

```
 public class TeamsController : ApiController
{ 
    private IGridironRepository<Team> _repo;

    public TeamsController(IGridironRepository<Team> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    // GET api/teams
    public IEnumerable<Team> Get()
    {
        var query = _repo.GetAll()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                    .ToList();
        return query;
    }

    // GET api/teams/5
    public Team Get(int id)
    {
        var query = _repo.FindBy(x => x.Id == id)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

        return query;
    }
 }
```

My app_start/ninjectwebcommon has this

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        //Support WebAPI (Webapicontrib.ioc.ninject)
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new NinjectResolver(kernel);

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind(typeof(IGridironRepository<>)).To(typeof(GridironRepository<>));
        kernel.Bind<GridironContext>().To<GridironContext>();
    }
```

and my global.asax looks like this

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
         AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
         GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
         FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
         RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
         BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
     }
}
```

Any clues or ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ninject's `Ninject.Web.WebAPI` nuget? If yes, don't use it. It is looking for files due to exceptions and trying to find the source, that's all. It would help to see the actual exceptions you are getting.

Comment: I am indeed using nuget to grab it. Should I just grab the ninject source and have the project point to it? I'll update with the exact exception when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be explicity at RegisterServices():

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(IGridironRepository<Team>).To(GridironRepository<Team>);
    kernel.Bind<GridironContext>().To<GridironContext>();
}
```